# PHP Invert/Negate Regex Pattern

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have the below string and I'm trying to do a `preg_replace` on anything that doesn't match the `12c` version number using a regular expression.

You can see the [working match](https://regex101.com/r/sV9pG5/4)

The expression I'm using matches the `12c` string format but I can't seem to figure out how to or if it's possible to invert/negate the regex match so instead of replacing the `12c`, replace everything but the `12c` so that only 12c of 11g etc is returned by the `preg_match` function.

**Code:**

```
preg_match('/(\s[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}\s)/', '', 'Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.0.2 - 64bit Production with the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing option');
```

**Pattern:**

```
/(\s[0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}\s)/
```

**String:**

```
Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.0.2 - 64bit Production with the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing option
```

Comment: Well, it is a bit unclear. Please clarify *replace everything but the 12c so that only 12c of 11g etc is returned by the preg_match function*.

Comment: Worth noting that your current regular expression will also match `64b` from 64bit if given the chance.

Comment: @apokryfos enough to change pattern - `([0-9]{2}[a-z]{1}(?=\W|$)))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want to get the text matched with the pattern:

```
if (preg_match('/([0-9]{2}[a-z]{1})/', 'Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.0.2 - 64bit Production with the Partitioning, OLAP, Data Mining and Real Application Testing option', $m))
  echo $m[1]; // 12c
```